# Installed python package with pip but can't import said package

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pip, package

I installed a python3 package called urllib3 using pip with the following command:

`pip install urllib3`

It seemed to be successful and when I type the command:

`pip list`

I get the following list which implies it is installed

[image: error]

But when I try to import in in the python console I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3`

I am using Python 3.8.5 (64bit) with a VS Code virtual enviroment, I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling I've also checked typos but I can't seem to find any.

Comment: It's apparently not installed in your virtual environment. Look up how to do that.

Comment: I followed the tutorial on installing packages from the VS Code website. I reselected the virtual enviroment, ran the command again and it still just says requirements statisfied so I presume the right enviroment has been selected

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pip3 install urllib3
```

As it can be possible you have also installed python2 on your machine.

Also try restarting your IDE.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention I only have this python version on the machine so that can't be the solution but I tried it and it gave me the requirement already statisfied message which is the same it gave for the original "pip" command.

Comment: I have also tried restarting and It unfortunately did nothing.

Comment: try this:-  `python -m pip install urllib3`

Answer (score 0):

You're paths might be mixed up: python, python3 as well as pip and pip3 might not point to the places you're expecting.

Try to validate that `which pip` and `which python` point to the same python installation.

Alternatively, you can install `urllib3` using `python -m pip install urllib3` instead of `pip install urllib3`.

Lastly, it might be a VS Code issue. See if the information on [selecting a Python interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) are helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with permissions for running scripts on the computer, I had to run the following command to enable permissions on my system:

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

This enabled the current user (me) to actually activate the venv when I opened powershell (I think) and run the pip install inside the venv instead of outside.

Note that I had the package installed globally since the PowerShell was not inside the venv.

Thanks for the help

Resolved!